# Tensorflow 1.15.4 doesn't install with python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, python-3.6, tensorflow1.15

I want to run a project from GitHub, which is available at the link [https://github.com/Mysteriousplayer/20210106], and I want to run it on my system. It is mentioned in the requirements.txt file that I need to install Python version 3.6.13 and TensorFlow version 1.15.4.

I have installed Python 3.6, but facing an error while installing TensorFlow, which says that this version of Python is not compatible with TensorFlow.
I got the error below in pyCharm terminal while using `pip install tensorflow`:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYdRC.png)

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /simple/tensorflow/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/tensorflow/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:852)'),)) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:852)'),)) - skipping
```

I have tried to install Python 3.6 and some specific versions of Tensorflow with the command below:
`pip install tensorflow==version_number` but it didn't work.